# How is the GUI for Windows Media Player 10 produced? Is it WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, windows-media-player

I'm sure [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) could produce a GUI replica, but is it actually made with WPF?

I've done some searching, but I'm not able to find what GUI library they used.

Comment: Windows Media Player is a Win32 application, not a .NET runtime, so if they're using WPF it's through some "voodoo magic".

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is almost certainly all C++ with mixed Assembly against standard WIN32 APIs and DirectX.  WPF came out with .NET 3.0 in late 2006 and Windows Media Player 10 came out in late 2004.  I would also add that there's nothing exceptionally unique about the Windows Media Player UI given that non-square windows and leveraging DirectX for animation outside of full screen has been around since the mid 90s all the way back to NT 4.0 and Windows 95.

Comment: DirectX eh? So it has a dependency on DirectX for the fancy GUI components?

Comment: Early Windows Media Player was very generic, but DirectX has been available for Windows all the way back to Windows 95 and NT 4.0.

Comment: And that is why I use Media Player Classic. ;)